# Can someone help please?

Tags: asymptote

Why is this not working?

```
[asy]
pair A = (5, 12);
pair B = (0, 0);
pair C = (5 + 2035/69, 0);
pair D = (10, 0);
pair E = (5/2 + 2035/138, -400/23);

draw(A--B--C--cycle);
draw(A--D);
draw(B--E--C);
draw(D--E);
draw(anglemark(B, A, D, 75), blue);
draw(anglemark(D, A, C, 75), blue);
draw(anglemark(E, B, D, 75), blue);

Path g=((0,0)--(5,12));

pathticks(path g, int n=1, real r=.5, spacing=1, s=2);

label("$A$", A, N);
label("$B$", B, NW);
label("$C$", C, NE);
label("$D$", D, NE);
label("$E$", E, S);
[/asy]
```

Comment: Please improve your question title by including some keywords into it. You may also provide a MWE that can help responding to your question

Comment: I think I can tell you why this does not work: to the best of my knowledge things like `anglemark` are not predefined. It happens to be defined in the nice [olympiad](https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/images/olympiad.asy) package, but how would I know if you are loading it. In your code there is no mention of that, nor do I know if you have it on your machine.

Comment: Indeed, loading `import olympiad;`, replacing `Path g=((0,0)--(5,12));` by `path g=((0,0)--(5,12));` and replacing the arguments of `pathticks` by proper arguments leads to a version that runs through without errors.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! Here is a version that runs through. If you have not already done so, download [olympiad.asy](https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/images/olympiad.asy). Then the following does not lead to errors:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=Label}
import olympiad;
pair pA = (5, 12);
pair pB = (0, 0);
pair pC = (5 + 2035/69, 0);
pair pD = (10, 0);
pair pE = (5/2 + 2035/138, -400/23);

draw(pA--pB--pC--cycle);
draw(pA--pD);
draw(pB--pE--pC);
draw(pD--pE);
draw(anglemark(pB, pA, pD, 75), blue);
draw(anglemark(pD, pA, pC, 75), blue);
draw(anglemark(pE, pB, pD, 75), blue);

path g=((0,0)--(5,12));

//pathticks(g,10);

label("$A$", pA, N);
label("$B$", pB, NW);
label("$C$", pC, NE);
label("$D$", pD, NE);
label("$E$", pE, S);

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the `pathticks`, I do not know what you had in mind.

**EDIT**: Changed the names of the points/pairs, big thanks to @O.G. for informing me about potential pitfalls.

Comment: Having `E` (or `N`, `S`, `W`) as variable names should be avoided. Indeed `E`,  `N`, `S`,  and `W` are defined as east, north, south and west to place labels. A uniform choice as  `pA`, `pB` etc should be better.

Comment: @O.G. Thank you! I have a lot to learn. The only point of this answer was to remember that `anglemark` got defined in `olympiad.asy`. Will fix this ASAP.

Comment: Many thanks for all your contributions. And  I made recently the `E` label error :)

Comment: Avoiding name `E`, `N`, `S`, `W` is somehow not natural. We can use it as usual, but whenever refer the north, just write `plain.N`, etc.